# React Native npm disable yellow warnings in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

How can I disable the annoying yellow warnings in my npm console?
It's impossible to see my own console.log output because of the massive warning output.

[image]

I tried already with:

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;

console.ignoredYellowBox = true;
```

But that helps just to disable the warnings in `EXPO` developer app.

Comment: where are you calling these? In index.js / index.ios.js ?

Comment: rather than disabling the yellowbox warnings you should solve the issues that causes the warnings.

Comment: the warning messages appear in every class. I do the backend developments and don't want to fix all the issues. I just would like to see my debugging output ;)

Answer (score 0):

That functionality got later moved into the `LogBox` package, but then rolled back as it was seen as a "mistake" as you shouldn't ignore warning messages.

More discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/34476#issuecomment-1240667794).

The way they did it is surely debatable but you can always override the `console.warn` function which is **highly**  discouraged.

To override it simply:

```
console.warn = () => {};
```